# Which Python version am using on Selenium testing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python for my website testing using Selenium, I want to generate the report not able to identify the Python version which I am writing, I am beginner please help out.

Answer (score 3):

For identifying the Python version please write a following script into the Terminal:

$ `python --version`

If you want to check your Python version into your codebase please write the following script into your project:

```
import platform


print(platform.python_version())
```